# C - printing greek letters in linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I have this paper, on C language, which requires some greek sentences to be printed in the terminal. 
In the code template that is given to us there is this line of code:

`system("chcp 1253>nul");`

This is supposed to print the greek characters. 
In my Ubuntu Terminal I see:

```
�������� ����� �� ����� ����� ��� �������� ���� ������
```

So, how can I print greek characters in my terminal?

Comment: chcp is from Windows. It has no effect on Ubuntu. Can you use UTF-8 locale?

Comment: Yes, I kinda figured that ... Can I use a UTF-8 locale where?

Comment: Can you use UTF-8 locale in your terminal?

Comment: in my locale I see: ``LANG=el_GR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
`` and all the LC_ are set to el_GR.UTF-8

Comment: It seems you can. Although in my locale utf-8 has a different name: LANG=en_US.utf8. So you can try to create a source file in UTF-8, compile it  and everything might be fine: `$ file main.cpp`,  `main.cpp: C source, UTF-8 Unicode text`

Comment: I get this ``exercise4.c: C source, UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators`` but still I get the �����

Comment: Can you actually print your greek characters in your terminal. I mean when you switch keyboard with Ctrl-Shift or Alt-Shift or whatever you use for switching keyboard?

Comment: well yes, I can type greek in the terminal and I can also see the files with the greek namesfor example.

Comment: You must call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: You also have to make sure your source is indeed in UTF-8 (it should normally be the case if you typed it yourself or copied/pasted from the paper). `cat yourprogram.c` in the terminal should show Greek string literals embedded in the code correctly.

Comment: did the setlocale(LC_ALL,"el_GR). Nothing. ``cat`` shows ����� still .

Comment: Don't know how `"el_GR)` compiles, call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` (nothing between the quotes). Also, are you using wide character literals? Are you using clang? Post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. I typed some greek myself and the work just fine with the setlocale(LC_ALL,"").  it was the code template I suppose that we were given.  Do you mind typing an answer so I can mark it correct and close this post? thanks for your help!

Comment: Your template must be in a legacy 8bit encoding rarher than UTF-8.

Comment: Answer posted but I don't really know what was the real reason for question marks. C source encoded as UTF-8 should probably work even without the call to setlocale (it is still recommended to make this call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported out of the box in most Linuxes. The only thing one must do is use

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

in the beginning of the program. This relies on the fact that UTF-8 is the default choice of encoding for users' locales. The standard says that this call switches to user's current locale. The default is to use the "C" locale which may or may not support national characters.

By default gcc interprets the source code as encoded in UTF-8. Compile-time options exist to change that, but it is recommendedd to keep everything in UTF-8 on Linux. Sources that come from Windows are probably not encoded in UTF-8 and need to be recoded. Use the `iconv` utility for that;l. If the source is associated with a particular legacy code page, try that code page name as the source encoding.

Answer (score 1):

A C program (comforming to ISO C99 or later, or POSIX.1 or later) that inputs or outputs non-ASCII text should use wide strings, wide I/O, and localization.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void)
{

    /* Tell the C library to use the current locale settings. */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    /* Standard output is used with the wide I/O functions. */
    fwide(stdout, 1);

    /* Print some Greek text. */
    wprintf(L"Γειά σου Κόσμε!\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that wide string literals are written using `L"..."` whereas normal (ASCII or narrow) string literals as `"..."`. Similarly, wide character constants (of type `wint_t`) are written with the `L` prefix; for example, `L'€'`.

---

When compiling, you do need to tell the compiler what character set the source code uses. In Linux, GCC uses the locale settings, but also provides an option `-finput-charset=windows-1252` to change it to Windows Western European, for example.

Rather than fiddle with the flags, I recommend you write a Bash helper script, say `to-utf8`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ ":$1" = ":-h" ] || [ ":$1" = ":--help" ]; then
    printf '\n'
    printf 'Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n' "$0"
    printf '       %s windows-1252 file.c [ ... ]\n' "$0"
    printf '\n'
    exit 0
fi

charset="$1"
shift 1

Work=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap "rm -f '$Work'" EXIT

for src in "$@" ; do
    iconv -f "$charset//TRANSLIT" -t UTF-8 "$src" > "$Work" || exit $?
    sed -e 's|\r$||' "$Work" > "$src" || exit $?
    printf '%s: Converted successfully.\n' "$src"
done

exit 0
```

If you want, you can install that system-wide using

```
sudo install -o 0 -g 0 -m 0755 to-utf8 /usr/bin/
```

The first command-line parameter is the source character set (use `iconv --list` to see them all), followed by a list of files to fix.

The script creates an automatically deleted temporary file. The `iconv` line converts the character set of each file to UTF-8, saving the result into the temporary file. The `sed` file changes any CRLF (`\r\n`) newlines to LF (`\n`), overwriting the contents of the file.

(Rather than use a second temporary file to hold the contents, having `sed` to direct its output to the original file, means the original file keeps its owner and group intact.)